# How to show a container / dialog next to an icon when the icon is tapped?

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm trying to create a screen that have bunch of container with a child of row that have a text  and a Icon (the red one - can be seen on the image). So when I click the icon I want to show a dialog right next to the icon. I tried using aligned_dialog but the positioning is really hard to do, I want it to be instantly next to the icon just like the image.

Is there any package or widget that I can use to achieve this ?

[image: Image that i want to achieve]

Comment: check the sources of `Tooltip` widget

Comment: can I show tooltip on the right side of the icon ?

Comment: in tooltip you can show only text - if you need any widget you have to create your custom "tooltip" - check the sources how they did it and based on that create your custom version

Answer (score 0):

You can check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/just_the_tooltip

It allow to specify a child of type Widget, so you can add what you want.